Asuka Error: Expected 0 type arguments. material.PersistentBottomSheetController<T> showBottomSheet<T>
While using asuka package by flutterando I encounter this error
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/asuka-2.2.0/lib/src/asuka_singleton.dart:186:12: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
  material.PersistentBottomSheetController<T> showBottomSheet<T>(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/asuka-2.2.0/lib/src/asuka_singleton_deprecated.dart:104:10: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
material.PersistentBottomSheetController<T> showBottomSheet<T>(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

but at the same time I'm using in my pubspec.yaml this version of it
asuka: ^2.0.1+3

Here is my flutter doctor -v:
[√]  Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.4, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.22631.3374], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.19.4 on channel stable at C:\Users\user\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 68bfaea224 (12 days ago), 2024-03-20 15:36:31 -0700
    • Engine revision a5c24f538d
    • Dart version 3.3.2
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java

[√] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.84.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM J810M (mobile) • 1f889607 • android-arm    • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows  • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.22631.3374]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 123.0.6312.59
    • Edge (web)        • edge     • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 123.0.2420.65

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Did anyone experienced a similar issue?
And if yes, how it solved?

I just found a pull request that someone did to fix it but it hasn't been accepted yet, here is what what fixed for me:
asuka:
git:
url: https://github.com/Flutterando/asuka.git
ref: 82e0b98497d19d42e974d8252b31d13fde8e4ffb
